# Need a Powershell script to ping port 22 of a Linux Server

Tags: powershell

Currently, I am using the below command to get the port status.

> Test-NetConnection -ComputerName "[Servername]" -Port 22 -InformationLevel Quiet

With the above command, I am only getting True or False. But, I need more.

I want to loop it with 5 minutes interval and 10 milliseconds time out.

Can anyone suggest how to do it?

Comment: remove the `-InformationLevel Quiet` since that is what tells the cmdlet to return _only_ a boolean. [*grin*]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modified script taken from the [PowerShell Code Repository](https://web.archive.org/web/20150405035615/http://poshcode.org/85) (author 'BSonPosh'):

```
$srv="google.com"
$port=80
$timeout=100 #timeout in miliseconds
$time=300 #Time to check in seconds
$verbose=$true

While($true){

    # Test-Port.ps1
    # Does a TCP connection on specified port (135 by default)

    $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

    # Create TCP Client
    $tcpclient = new-Object system.Net.Sockets.TcpClient

    # Tell TCP Client to connect to machine on Port
    $iar = $tcpclient.BeginConnect($srv,$port,$null,$null)

    # Set the wait time
    $wait = $iar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne($timeout,$false)

    # Check to see if the connection is done
    if(!$wait)
    {
        # Close the connection and report timeout
        $tcpclient.Close()
        if($verbose){Write-Host "Connection Timeout"}
        Return $false
    }
    else
    {
        # Close the connection and report the error if there is one
        $error.Clear()
        $tcpclient.EndConnect($iar) | out-Null
        if(!$?){if($verbose){write-host $error[0]};$failed = $true}
        $tcpclient.Close()
    }

    # 
    if($failed){Write-Host "Error occured"}else{Write-Host "Ping successfull"}
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $time
   }
```

Comment: Thank you Very Much. the Script work like a chram.